# gitlab-ci-runner avoid "failed to remove" error messages on next run (avoid tracking of certain files)

Tags: sudo, gitlab-ci-runner

Might be a newbie question for gitlab-runner users.  in  my setup gitlab-runner runs with bash shell a script which produces an image file.
So basically it creates an empty file, sudo mounts it with the loop back device and , create a files system on the loop back device and copies files into it. At the end of the script the filesystem is unmounted.

This sucessfully runs also in gitlab-runner.

After one succesful run, the runner starts to spit out error messages about "failed to remove" files and a confusing "permission denied" message.

Data points:
I have noticed, that this happens before the actual script re-runs. The error messages all reference  files which were originally created in the mounted image in the last run - and of course they are not there anymore, as the assembled image was unmounted in the last step of the  script. and this run should newly assemble in this image.

How can i avoid that gitlab-runner keeps track of these files?  They should not be tracked at all.